# question on research topics in divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, divergent-series

We always talk about series being divergent or convergent. In elementary maths, we are very much interested in convergent series: we perform calculus, use them for approximations, use them as functions, and so on. As a result, there is so much to say about convergent series.

Just a question, without the need for substantive mathematical depth, do we have ever had analysis on divergent series? What can we do with them? Is there research being performed on them? What would be the themes, topics (even if they are just a quick overview/general background) on what they are about.

I am just interested to know.

Comment: Yes.  Start with the good old classic *Divergent Series* by G. H. Hardy.

Comment: I wouldn't know about **active** research about divergent series. But see the references [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Bochner-Riesz_means). Harmonic analysis has use of some resummation methods

Comment: Yes, there have been a number of books published on divergent series.  Asymptotic series can sometimes be used to give very good approximations to functions.  Even though the series diverges eventually, it comes close to the function before it starts to diverge.  This can be useful even when convergent series are known, if they converge slowly.    It appears that there are many more advanced applications, but I don't know about them.  Look at the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) for a start.